# Can we migrate Autosuggestions from one production GSA Box to Another Production GSA Box

Tags: google-search, autosuggest, google-search-api, google-search-appliance, google-search-platform

We are migrating from one production GSA box to another production GSA server. We wanted to migrate all autosuggestions from one production box to another.

I got the reply from Google Support as follows:

> Currently there is no way of doing so, we have a feature request #
>   4411407 for allowing to import query suggestions on the box. 
>   Currently we do not have an ETA when this will be implemented.

First my question where and how I can check the status of  #4411407.

Second let me know if autosuggestion is Collection / Frontend specific?

Becuase I am planning to perform the below task:

1) Export the suggestion in text file from first GSA Box.

2) Write a script to read each line from that files and execute the search query against new GSA Box.

3) This will create a new autosuggestion list in new GSA Box.

Regards,

Jayesh Bhoyar

Answer (score 2):

Currently, there's no way to import this data. The solution you mentioned of exporting and writing a script works very well, and is usually simple enough to do.

Answer (score 0):

You ask FR status to your Partner Operation Manager.

Otherwise, you can export suggestion data on admin console by frontend/collection specific.

Comment: I can export; but there is no way to import it in new appliance.